# Swift DRY collectionView(_ cellForItemAt) call

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift4

I find myself doing this repetitive code a lot, when I have different kinds of cells. Is there a way to DRY it up? Or is it as good as it could be.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch cells[indexPath.item].type {
        case .aCell:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ACellID, for: indexPath) as! ACell
            cell.data = somedata
            return cell
        case .bCell:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: BCellID, for: indexPath) as! BCell
            cell.data = somedata
            return cell
        case .cCell:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CCellID, for: indexPath) as! CCell
            cell.data = somedata
            return cell 
        }
    }
```

I am thinking to have all cells adopt a `protocol` and put them in an array

Comment: I see the same module  var what is the key difference between them ??

Comment: For what it's worth, I have this pattern in a lot of different code bases, and I've personally felt that any further attempts to remove duplication violated some other programming principle, or just didn't improve the solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you can use a protocol to which all your cells could conform to and extend your cell type enum to return cell id so you don't need to switch every time to dequeue.

```
enum CellType {
    case aCell, bCell, cCell

    var id: String {
        switch self {
        case .aCell: return "aCellId"
        case .bCell: return "bCellId"
        case .cCell: return "cCellId"
        }
    }
}

protocol CellData {

    // Remove since you probably have your modlue type.
    typealias Module = String

    var type: CellType { get }
    var modlues: [Module] { get } // Module type
}

protocol CommonCellProperty: AnyObject {
    var data: CellData! { get }
}

typealias CommonCell = CommonCellProperty & UICollectionViewCell

class MasterCell: UICollectionViewCell, CommonCellProperty {
    var data: CellData! // set data
}
class HolderCell: UICollectionViewCell, CommonCellProperty {
    var data: CellData! // set data
}
//...

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var cells: [CellData] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cellData: CellData = cells[indexPath.section]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellData.type.id, for: indexPath) as! CommonCell

        //cell.data = somedata

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cells.count
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if that's really your code pattern and the only thing that's different is the identifier, I'd suggest creating a dictionary where the key is the cell type and the value is the identifier:

```
//Create a dictionary to map from cell type to identifier
let cellIDs = [
  .aCell: ACellID,
  .bCell: BCellID,
  .cCell: CCellID
]

//Define a common class for the different cell types
class MyCell: UICollectionViewViewCell {
  var data: Data
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  let cell: MyCell
  let cellType = cells[indexPath.item].type
  let cellIdentifier = cellIDs[cellType]
  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
    withReuseIdentifier: 
    cellIdentifier, 
    for: indexPath) as! MyCell
  cell.data = someData
  return cell
}
```

Alternatively, add another field `identifier` to your array `cells` that contains the type for each cell, and just fetch the cell's reuse identifier from that array like you're currently doing with the cell type.

Comment: In the OP, the cells are instantiated as different UITableViewCell subclasses. This solution won't work for that.